# How to appply a template to a generic control?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have a generic control:

```
public class BarChart<T> : ContentView
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

and an associated template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BarChartControlTemplate">
    [...]
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:BarChart`1}">
    <Setter 
        Property="ControlTemplate"
        Value="{StaticResource BarChartControlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Apparently, what I am trying to do is not possible (the method `OnApplyTemplate()` is never called).

If I specialize my control (like this for instance `public class IntBarChart : ContentView`), there is obviously no problem.
But it's not a solution that suits me (if you tell me it's the only solution, I'll go with it, but I'll think it's a shame).

I thought of making a base control (not generic off course) but again, no method is called.

```
public class BarChart : ContentView
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}

public class BarChart<T> : BarChart
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to apply a global template to a generic control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the document [Xamarin.Forms control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template) and it gives the way to make the custom control. In addition, I used the generic way to use the `ControlTemplate` and it can not work. This is not an effective way to custom the templates.